# SQLite count number of occurence of word in a string

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to count number of occurrences of a word in a string for example ,

```html
[{"lastUpdatedDateTime":{"timestamp":1.54867752522E12},"messageStatus":"DELIVERED","phoneNumber":"+916000060000"},{"lastUpdatedDateTime":{"timestamp":1548677525220},"messageStatus":"DELIVERED","phoneNumber":"+916000060000"}]
```

in above string i want to count no of occurrences of a word 'DELIVERED' here it is 2.
i want to get result 2. pls help me on this. i should have to use only sql query to achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your table's name is `tablea` and the column's name is `col`:

```
SELECT 
(LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col, '"DELIVERED"', ''))) 
/ 
LENGTH('"DELIVERED"') as counter 
from tablea
```

remove every occurrence of `"DELIVERED"` and subtract the length of the string from the original string and finally divide the result with the length of `"DELIVERED"`

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help. It works in sqlite browser. But, replace not supporting  within Room database query like its not an valid query

Comment: I have never used Room, but it seems strange that it does not allow a valid sql statement.

Comment: Beautiful, i used it for ordering by "counter"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a table something like:

```
CREATE TABLE example(json TEXT);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('[{"lastUpdatedDateTime":{"timestamp":1.54867752522E12},"messageStatus":"DELIVERED","phoneNumber":"+916000060000"},{"lastUpdatedDateTime":{"timestamp":1548677525220},"messageStatus":"DELIVERED","phoneNumber":"+916000060000"}]');
```

and your instance of sqlite has the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension enabled:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "Number Delivered"
FROM example AS e
JOIN json_each(e.json) AS j
WHERE json_extract(j.value, '$.messageStatus') = 'DELIVERED';
```

gives you:

```
Number Delivered
----------------
2
```

This will return the total number of matching entries from all rows in the table as a single value. If you want one result per row instead, it's an easy change but the exact details depend on your table definition. Adding `GROUP BY e.rowid` to the end of the query will work in most cases, though.

In the long run it's probably a better idea to store each object in the array as a single row in a table, broken up into the appropriate columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to it's not working got error in json_each and also room sqlite db doesn't support json_each